# How to use Prototype and jQuery on the same page without problems

Tags: jquery, prototype

I'm trying to use both prototype and jquery libraries together on a page but when I import both libraries, its either the jQuery code works and prototype code doesn't or the other way round. So I need to know how to use both codes effectively on the same page or is it impossible? Thanks as you give your useful answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `jquery` and `prototype` use the `$` variable. You can still use both libraries together by putting `jquery` in "no conflict mode". When you do, you can replace the `$()` alias for the `jquery()` function at the same time:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

For more details: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/